# How to get data from a file stored in json?

Tags: android, json

Actually, I have made a json file which I have stored in the storage option of Firebase. Now, I want to get data that I have stored in my android app. I copied the url of the file in the storage. I have also made a pojo file to use it. But I don't know what to do afterwards. Please Help!!!

Comment: Gson http://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library

Comment: https://www.numetriclabz.com/firebase-integration-in-android-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `loadJson` function with [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
private <T> T loadJson(Class<T> type, String fileName) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = "";
    ClassLoader classLoader = type.getClassLoader();
    try {
        json = IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Use this function by calling:

```
loadJson(myClass.class, "directory/file.json"
```